# How to generate IUPAC code from nucleotides?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I want to find the IUPAC equivalent to 2 different nucleotides.

Example: I have A and C and I want M.
Or: I have R and T and I want D.

Is there a method for doing that in Biopython? (It sound easy but I only found method for doing that using alignment and that's not appropriate in my case.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for the dictionaries in `Bio.Data.IUPACData`, like:

```
>>> from Bio.Data import IUPACData
>>> d = {v:k for k,v in IUPACData.ambiguous_dna_values.items()}
>>> d['AC']
'M'
```

Note, reversing the dictionary mapping here means we lose a key since `'X'` and `'N'` both map to `'GATC'`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about this!  
But since I wanted d['RT'] to return D, I had tu use a bit ugly trick:  
`d = {tuple(set(v)):k for k,v in IUPACData.ambiguous_dna_values.items()}  
and d[tuple(set(IUPACData.ambiguous_dna_values['R'] + 'T'))]  # Convert 'R' to 'AG'`  

The tuple(set()) things allow me to use the IUPACData.ambiguous_dna_values dictionnary with either 'ATG' or 'GAT'...  

It works but do you know if an esiest way exist?

Comment: @Liad I'm not very clear on what you want to do, but maybe try `d = {frozenset(v):k for k,v in IUPACData.ambiguous_dna_values.items()}` and then `d[frozenset('ATG')]` and `d[frozenset('GAT')]` both return `'D'`

Comment: It was a bit ambiguous yeah :) I didn't know about `frozenset` and it does the same as `tuple(set())` but better! And yeah my objective was to do `d[('ATG')]` and `d[('GAT')]` without writing the dictionary myself. So thanks for the help :)